# android load fragments do imposible access to imageview

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

In OnCreate I call this fragment:

```
if(internet == true){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new PasarProjectos();

        /*if(esLandscape == true){
            contenedor_salvado = findViewById(R.id.contenedor_info);
        }*/

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putBoolean("esLandscape", esLandscape);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

        }
        findViewById(R.id.imageView17).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PasarProjNoMenu.this, InicioNoLogin.class));
            }
        });
    }else{
        startActivity(new Intent(PasarProjNoMenu.this, InicioNoLogin.class));
    }
```

and finish the method of onCreate

Later, I call another method that I try localize to another view

```
public void ensenarProjMismaPantalla(String id_s) { //un inflate rellenando los datos y punto

    Log.d("La acción ","rellenar campo primero");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fotoProj);

}
```

The imageview I know is continuous;y on the screen, because I can see it when the app runs, but the app throws a nullpointerexception error

Comment: please write where you call this method: `ensenarProjMismaPantalla()`

Comment: into the fragment "PasarProjectos.java"

Comment: i leave the code into an answer

Comment: show me code, I want to see it, how you call ensenarProjMismaPantalla(), and what parameters you pass.

Comment: Made English clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, into the fragment i call the method to this way:

```
((PasarProjNoMenu)context).ensenarProjMismaPantalla(int_parameter);
```

The problem was when i try call the same class 2 times at the same activity.

Thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

i call the main activity from the fragment, i know that i can

```
 public void anadirFragmentConDatos(
        final String id_s, String nombre_s, String ticket_s, String porfinanciar_s, String imagen_s, final int pos){
    //generamos el inflater para poder añadir el hijo
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ListadoPrj);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pre_project, null);

    addView.setId(Integer.parseInt(id_s));

    addView.setOnTouchListener(
            new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (esLandscape == false) {
                        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Me ha pulsado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SociosInversores si = new SociosInversores();

                                String Uid = si.Uid;

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProjectFullScreen.class);
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                                bundle.putString("Uid", Uid);
                                bundle.putString("Pid", id_s);

                                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                                startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }else{
                        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                //cargar en el lateral
                                PasarProjNoMenu ppnm = new PasarProjNoMenu();
                                ppnm.ensenarProjMismaPantalla(id_s);

                        }
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            }
    );

    //añadimos el view
    parent.addView(addView); /*the rest of the method*/}
```

I'm declaring the class correctly, i think.